# I can't seem to retrieve the hashed password from mongoDB with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, hash

I'm trying to make a simple login but whenever I try to get the hashed password the mongo console throws me this error:

> ReferenceError: test is not defined

for some reason every time I insert data it goes into an admin db which I don't create it is there by default:

> show dbs
>
> admin     0.000GB
>
> local     0.000GB

this is my connection:

```
var db = null;
 MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/firstApp", function(err, dbconn){
    if(!err){
       console.log("Connected");
       db = dbconn;
    }
});
```

And this is how I try to login (right now is commented because I want to get the hashed password.

```
app.put('/users/signin', function(req, res, next){

db.collection('users', function(err, usersCollection){

    usersCollection.findOne({username: req.body.usern}, function(err, user){
        console.log(user.password);
        /*bcrypt.compare(req.body.pass, user.password, function(err, result){

            if(result) {

                return res.send();

            } else {
                return res.status(400).send();
            }

        });*/
    });

  });
});
```

However when I try that `console.log()` command, it throws me this:

> ReferenceError: user is not defined

PS. I'm learning.

Comment: Maybe you getting error? Do you check what's contain err object?

Comment: when I dont try to log the `user.password` and log the error it says `null` and when I try to get the `user.password` i throws me this error `Cannot read property 'password' of null`

Comment: Can you confirm that user is created?

Comment: @SkyQ yes it is. I use `db.users.find()` and it's there

Comment: As i can see you are trying to connect firstApp DB, but it doesn't exist. Maybe in this is problem. Try to create one collection(eg. test) in that firstApp DB. In mongo custom DBs only exist if has at least on collection.

Comment: The firstApp DB exists and there is a collection called users. I verified it.

Comment: I'd try to make a breakpoint before you make a db call and make sure that req.body.usern is correct also.